# ScrollRect. Начальная позиция, во время запуска игры

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Во время запуска игры, мой `ScrollRect` располагает объект по середине поля, хотелось бы, чтобы объект по умолчанию был привязан к левому верхнему углу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Иерархия объектов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У скролл бара есть значение `value`, которое изменяется от 0 до 1.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Например для скролла с `Direction = LeftToRight` для крайнего левого положения нужно поставить значение `value` в 0.  У вертикального `TopToBottom` тоже.

Думаю вам нужно их по дефолту поставить в такое значение в инспекторе (либо скриптом, если хочется) и всё.

и не забыть эти скроллбары добавить в `scrollRect`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проблема не в `ScrollBar`.
Проблема в том, что у меня всё по середине стоит.

Comment: @PlasticBlock так в чем проблема поставить значения на ноль? непонятно)

Comment: Нет, не в этом проблема. Тут `ScrollRect` вообще не причём. Чтобы я там ни делал.